# React-Native: pressing the button twice only updates the this.setState

Tags: react-native, setstate

The App is simple.. Conversion of gas.. What im trying to do is multiply the `Inputed Amount` by `2` as if it is the formula. So i have a `index.js` which is the `Parent`, and the `Calculate.component.js` who do all the calculations. What i want is, `index.js` will pass a `inputed value` to the `component` and do the calculations and pass it again to the `index.js` to display the calculated amount.

**Index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PickerComponent from './Picker.Component';
import CalculateAVGAS from './Calculate.component';

export default class PickerAVGAS extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.getParam('headerTitle'),
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomColor: 'white',
    },
  });

  state = {
    gasTypeFrom: 'Gas Type',
    gasTypeTo: 'Gas Type',
    input_amount: '',
    pickerFrom: false,
    pickerTo: false,
    isResult: false,
    result: '',
  };

  inputAmount = amount => {
    this.setState({ input_amount: amount });
    console.log(amount);
  };

  onResult = value => {
    this.setState({
      result: value,
    });
    console.log('callback ', value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Input
          placeholder="Amount"
          multiline
          keyboardType="numeric"
          onChangeText={amount => this.inputAmount(amount)}
        />
        <ResultContainer>
          <ResultText>{this.state.result}</ResultText>
        </ResultContainer>
        <CalculateContainer>
          <CalculateAVGAS
            title="Convert"
            amount={this.state.input_amount}
            total="total"
            titleFrom={this.state.gasTypeFrom}
            titleTo={this.state.gasTypeTo}
            // isResult={this.toggleResult}
            result={value => this.onResult(value)}
          />
        </CalculateContainer>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**CalculateAVGAS / component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default class CalculateAVGAS extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    amount: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    titleFrom: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    titleTo: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  state = {
    totalVisible: true,
    result: '',
  };

  onPressConversion = () => {
    const formula = this.props.amount * 2;
    const i = this.props.result(this.state.result);
    this.setState({ result: formula });
    // console.log(this.state.result);
    console.log('func()');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonContainer onPress={() => this.onPressConversion()}>
        <ButtonText>{this.props.title}</ButtonText>
      </ButtonContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

After doing this, the `setState` only updates when pressing the `Convert button` **twice**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue here is that you want to display information in the parent component, but you are saving that info in the child component's state.
Just pass amount, and result, to the stateless child component (CalculateAVGAS).

It's usually best to keep child components "dumb" (i.e. presentational) and just pass the information they need to display, as well as any functions that need to be executed, as props.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default class CalculateAVGAS extends Component {
  onPressConversion = () => {
    this.props.result(this.props.amount * 2);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonContainer onPress={() => this.onPressConversion()}>
        <ButtonText>{this.props.title}</ButtonText>
      </ButtonContainer>
    );
  }
}

const ButtonContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity``;

const ButtonText = styled.Text``;
```

Parent component looks like:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import CalculateAVGAS from './Stack';

export default class PickerAVGAS extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.getParam('headerTitle'),
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomColor: 'white',
    },
  });

  state = {
    gasTypeFrom: 'Gas Type',
    gasTypeTo: 'Gas Type',
    input_amount: null,
    pickerFrom: false,
    pickerTo: false,
    isResult: false,
    result: null,
  };

  inputAmount = amount => {
    this.setState({input_amount: amount});
  };

  onResult = value => {
    this.setState({
      result: value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Input
          placeholder="Amount"
          multiline
          keyboardType="numeric"
          onChangeText={amount => this.inputAmount(amount)}
        />
        <ResultContainer>
          <ResultText>{this.state.result}</ResultText>
        </ResultContainer>
        <CalculateContainer>
          <CalculateAVGAS
            title="Convert"
            amount={this.state.input_amount}
            total="total"
            titleFrom={this.state.gasTypeFrom}
            titleTo={this.state.gasTypeTo}
            result={value => this.onResult(value)}
          />
        </CalculateContainer>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const Container = styled.View``;

const ResultContainer = styled.View``;

const ResultText = styled.Text``;

const CalculateContainer = styled.View``;

const Input = styled.TextInput``;
```

Comment: I wish i could, but need more 15 reputations to upvote :/

Comment: I see :(  however I do think you can accept the answer by clicking checkmark underneath the upvote/downvote buttons.